# search an item of sublist in another list of list by position

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list created like

```
biglist=[['A'], ['C', 'T'], ['A', 'T']]
```

and I will have another list like

```
smalllist=[['C'], ['T'], ['A', 'T']]
```

So, I want to check wheter an item in small list contains in that specific index of biglist, if not append to it.

so, making

```
biglist=[['A','C'], ['C', 'T'], ['A', 'T']]
```

so, 'C' from fist sublist of smalllist was added to first sublist of biglist. but not for second and third.

I tried like

```
dd=zip(biglist, smalllist)
for each in dd:
    ll=each[0].extend(each[1])
    templist.append(list(set(ll)))
```

but get errors

```
templist.append(list(set(ll)))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, you should try this:

*// This will only work, if smalllist is shorter than biglist*

**SCRIPT:**

```
biglist   = [['A'], ['C', 'T'], ['A', 'T']]
smalllist = [['C'], ['T'], ['A', 'T']]

for i, group in enumerate(smalllist):
    for item in group:
        if item not in biglist[i]:
            biglist[i].append(item)
```

**DEMO:**

```
print(biglist)
# [['A', 'C'], ['C', 'T'], ['A', 'T']]
```

Comment: yeah, I always go for loops in the last resort if i dont find any list comprehension, set operations. I was actually working this way before seeing your answer and you read my mind. Thanks a lot. I don't know how fast it is compared to other techniques.

Comment: On Python3: mine: `1.378441910026595`; ovgolovin's: `6.968630363931879`; bsoist's: `5.993933744030073`

Comment: +1 for speed - both answering and implementation @PeterVaro I'd be interested to know if that were different if we were using sets and not lists. (edit - the speed data, I mean)

Comment: @Ananta if you think my answer was helpful to you, don't hesitate, to accept it! Thanks;)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, `extend` in Python doesn't return the list itself after extending. So `ll` in your case is `None`. Just put `ll=each[0]` on the second line in the loop, and your solution should start working.

Still, I'm not getting, why you don' keep your elements in `set`s in the first place. This would avoid you from having to convert from `list` to `set` and then backwards.

I would just `or` sets instead of appending to the list and then filtering out duplicates by resorting to `set` and then to `list`.

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> templist = []
>>> for els1,els2 in izip(biglist,smalllist):
    joined = list(set(els1) | set(els2))
    templist.append(joined)


>>> templist
[['A', 'C'], ['C', 'T'], ['A', 'T']]
```

---

Keeping elements in `set`s in the first place seems to be the fastest in Python 3 even for such small amount of elements in each set (see comments):

```
biglist=[set(['A']), set(['C', 'T']), set(['A', 'T'])]
smalllist=[set(['C']), set(['T']), set(['A', 'T'])]

for els1,els2 in zip(biglist,smalllist):
    els1.update(els2)

print(biglist)
```

Ouput:

```
[{'A', 'C'}, {'C', 'T'}, {'A', 'T'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah as you said I changed it to have set in the first place

Comment: This solution is much much slower than the one I suggested. `6.968630363931879` vs `1.378441910026595`

Comment: @PeterVaro You are modifying initial list in-place. In my code I created a new list for modified objects. If it's OK to modify initial list, I think it would be faster to use `set` in the first place. This would avoid redundant conversions and will make the solution even faster.

Comment: @ovgolovin so what is your solution with the sets then if you can modify the initial list?

Comment: @PeterVaro In the OP's code, they used `templist`, so I decided a new list is expected. If you feel like, try this solution with inplace modifications http://ideone.com/vZNNuy . But the solution with `set`s will benefit the most, if the original lists will contain data in `set`s. In case of the OP's code this will work.

Comment: @ovgolovin the solution you suggested at ideone, is faster, then the one you suggested here, but slower then modifying the initial list. (`3.7937895199283957`)

Comment: @PeterVaro On ideone I'm modifying initial list. But in the middle there are conversions to set and backwards. So, yeah, it is still slower. Please, can you benchmark this code (http://ideone.com/SjKtel), I'm just curious!

Comment: @PeterVaro I used `set`s in initial lists. They are defined at the beginning of the code. I'm still assuming that version with `list`s may be faster, as `list` is highly optimized in Python (and `set`s may be not that well written).

Comment: @ovgolovin now that's better! that is actually faster than mine! (in this turn yours was: `1.415848296135664` mine was: `1.642207908211276`)

Comment: @PeterVaro Thanks! I'm really surprised. Because I know that `list`s are very well written in Python and highly optimized. As the lists are very very small (several elements) I expected them to be faster than `set`s. So now I know that `set`s in Python 3 are also very good to be used (even for small number of elements).

Answer (score 2):

```
[list(set(s+b)) for (s,b) in zip(smalllist,biglist)]
```

Comment: Thanks, How much experience does it take to think one liners like this list comprehension?

Comment: This solution is much much slower than the one I suggested. `5.993933744030073` vs `1.378441910026595`

Comment: That's a very difficult question to answer. I tend to think in mathematical terms, so that's how I picked up stuff like this. Just keep in mind that it is not any faster than doing loops, and can be harder to read. Peter's solution is better, but I didn't see it until after I posted.

Comment: and mine doesn't scale nearly as well

Comment: wow, peter, you answered my question on time  too...may be loop is not bad.

Comment: @Ananta this is not about loops, this is about createing a new list, with zip, and then creating sets and then convert them to lists.. this is overhead, I guess.

Comment: yes, function calls are expensive. Especially in Python ( or so I've always been told ).

Comment: @PeterVaro Reasoning about Python performance is slightly difficult, as Python performance differs from implementation to implementation. From what I know, CPython reuses the same tuple in `izip` in Python 2 and in `zip` in Python 3. It is really really very efficient implementation by what the author of this core Python code says. What may be sluggish is conversions to `set`s and then backwards.

Comment: @ovgolovin you probably right about izip/zip (when I timed your version, I replaced `itertools.izip()` with `zip` -- as I'm on Python 3)

Comment: @PeterVaro agreed re: speculating, but my point was that I am calling the functions multiple times. I meant to include a comment about that in the answer and then decided to comment instead. because of the repeated function calls, mine does not scale well to large lists ( I'm assuming ).